# How to Login and show other html/php page using REST API

Tags: php, mysql, json, api

I want to use REST API for login.

I have made two files (login_api.php and login.html)

How to navigate to other URL (say home.html or home.php) after successful login ?

**login_api.php** this file contains code for REST API.

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
require "config.php";
require "user.php";
$users = new User();

header('Content-Type: application/json');
if (isset($_POST['req'])) 
{ 
    switch ($_POST['req']) 
    {
      case "login":
        if (is_array($_SESSION['user'])) {
          die(json_encode([
            "status" => true,
            "message" => "Already signed in"
          ]));
        }
        $pass = $users->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
        if ($pass!==false) { $_SESSION['user'] = $pass; }
        echo json_encode([
          "status" => is_array($pass),
          "message" => is_array($pass) ? "OK" : "Error"
        ]);
        break;

      case "logoff":
        unset($_SESSION['user']);
        echo json_encode([
          "status" => true,
          "message" => "OK"
        ]);
        break;
    }
    echo "eee :" . $_SESSION['user'];
}
else
{
    echo "error";
}
?>
```

**login.html** this is html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form action="login_api.php" method="post" target="_blank">
      Name <input type="text" name="username" required/><br>
      Password <input type="text" name="password" required/><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="req" value="login">
      <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see how any of this is REST, or an API (besides in the literal sense).

Comment: You appear to be passing JSON back from your login PHP code, but I dont see any AJAX code(javascript) anywhere in your `login.html` page that would be able to process that returned data??

Comment: Your login.html must send an ajax request to the login.php file then listen to the server response and action accordingly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

send AJAX request from login.html file here is the code for it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form id="idForm" action="login_api.php" method="post" target="_blank">
      Name <input type="text" name="username" required/><br>
      Password <input type="text" name="password" required/><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="req" value="login">
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Create"/>
    </form>
  </body>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$("#idForm").submit(function(e) {


    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               console.log(data); // show response from the php script in console.
           }
         });

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, i added this code in login.html, now on submit, nothing happens!

Comment: change `var url = form.attr('login_api.php');` to `var url = form.attr('action');`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile oh, sorry I just saw the silly mistake.

Comment: @AtharvaMehta: try it now. done the changes.

Comment: It's working now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AtharvaMehta ok please accept the answer, so that the Question can be closed.